# Switch uppercase and lowercase of a string

Tags: racket

I'm doing a question where it asks me to convert all uppercases in a string to lowercases and lowercases to uppercases, and all other characters remain the same.

Below is my code:

```
(define (switch-case str)
  (list->string
  (cons
  (cond
    [(char-lower-case? (first (string->list str))) (char-upcase (first 
(string->list str)))]
    [(char-upper-case? (first (string->list str))) (char-downcase (first 
(string->list str)))]
    [else (first (string->list str))])
  (switch-case (rest (string->list str))))))
```

The error message for str "ABC" is:
    string->list: expects a string, given (cons #\B (cons #\C empty))
Can somebody tell me what has gone wrong with my code? Thx

Answer (score 1):

The recursive call is on the wrong type. You pass `[List-of Character]` to `switch-case`, but it expects `String`.

```
; String -> String
(define (switch-case str)
  (list->string
   (cons
    (swapcase nestr)
    (switch-case
     (rest (string->list str)) ; the type of this expression is [List-of Character]
                 ))))
```

Follow this template:

```
; [List-of Character] -> [List-of Character]
(define (switch-case-charlist cl)
  (cond [(empty? cl) ...]
        [else (... (first cl) ... (switch-case-charlist (rest cl)))]))

; Character -> Character
(define (swap-case-character c)
  ...)

; String -> String
(define (swap-case-string s)
  (list->string (... (string->list s))))
```